# ¿Se puede usar un NAS para hacer hospedaje web?

Tags: hosting, dns, local-storage, localhost, almacenamiento

Soy desarrollador web y llevo ya vario tiempo trabajando con la misma compañía de hospedaje.
Hace unas semanas empecé a involucrarme con FreeNAS en donde comparto archivos a toda mi red local y veo que se pueden compartir los archivos incluso fuera de mi red local bajos distintos protocolos de red lo cual me hace pensar que podría yo mismo hospedar mis páginas web. Sin embargo no se si esto podría funcionar y de ser así, ¿Cómo podría enlazar mi nombre de dominio a mi servidor local (NAS)?

Espero me puedan apoyar con mi duda. Excelente tarde.

Comment: La pregunta pudiera terminar cerrada pues es demasiado amplia, considera leer [ask]

Comment: Podrías si tienes IP pública, si es IP dinámica de alguna manera se puede lidiar con eso. La principal consideración es que tu ancho de banda de subida desde tu red local puede terminar siendo el ancho de banda de descarga fuera de la red. Es muy común que las conexiones sean asimétricas, siendo la velocidad de subida mucho menor (alrededor del 10%) que la de descarga.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, ya estoy haciendo pruebas con lo que me comentaron.

Espero pronto tener avances.

Excelente día.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si podrías usarlo pero tendrías que tener algunas cosas en claro:

1)Si la ip es dinámica podrías con "NO-IP" resolverlo.

2)Tendrías que saber tu velocidad de bajada y subida, y comparar en donde estas ahora para corroborar que no satures el ancho de banda de tu Internet y se caiga tu web.

3)Tendrías que ver si los puertos del tu modem están abiertos para permitir el trafico.

Una ves que tengas resueltas esas 3 cosas, podrías pensar en alojar tu mismo la web.

Después podes ver el tema de costos de luz, que hacer si te atacan con DDoS etc.

Espero que te resulte útil la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, ya estoy haciendo pruebas con lo que me comentaron.

Espero pronto tener avances.

Excelente día.

Comment: No denada. Para eso estamos para ayudar!. Te deseo éxitos.